# Can one override my const C++ member function returning a const pointer to a internal non-const array using const_cast?

Tags: c++, const-cast

I'm learning c++ and came across this const_cast operator. Consider the following example:

```
class Test
{  
  private:
    char name[100];
  public:
    Test(const char* n) { std::strncpy(name, n, 99); name[99]=0; }
    const char* getName() const { return name; }
}
```

Now a user can do

```
Test t("hi");
const_cast<char*>(t.getName())[0] = 'z'; //modifies private data...
```

Is this fine ? I mean modifying private data since the purpose of return const char* was to prevent changing private data. How do I prevent this ? (without using std::string)

Comment: The reason why casts have such a hideous syntax in C++ is to discourage people from using them (seriously!).  `const` only works as long as people don't intentionally circumvent it, but it's not meant to do that. The purpose is to avoid accidential modification, and it does that just fine. There is nothing you can do to prevent someone from maliciously breaking your code if they want. They could also write `#define private public` and there is nothing you could do.

Comment: You can invent much simpler examples of `const_cast` being used incorrectly.  For example, `const char *str = "foo"; const_cast<char *>(str)[0] = 'b';`.

Comment: As a sideways (and more "C++") solution, don't expose pointers to private data members, instead store a private `std::string`, and if you really really don't want anyone to modify it expose it by copy (as const-references could also be const-cast away).

Comment: @Oli `str` is of type `char*` and I don't think there is any need of `const_cast`. Also, isn't it that you are trying to modify the constant string literal whose behavior is undefined?

Comment: @user803563 : If you understand that his example causes UB, how do you not also understand that _your_ example causes UB? :-P

Comment: @idjarn. My example doesn't modify `const` data. It only changes the pointer type.

Comment: @user803563: `str` is of type `char const[4]` which decays to `char const*`. It is deprecated to use `char*` to point to a statically allocated string and it is undefined behavior to try and modify it (with or without `const`).

Comment: BTW, accessing `const` members has some usage if you're doing  debugging or for unit testing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No this is not 'fine'. Though it is possible. But C++ doesn't force good behavior on programmers. It mainly allows you to declare things in a way that show their intended use. If a programmer decides to trick around that protection he should know what he is doing.

**Bjarne Stroustrup**: Yes. That's the new cast syntax. Casts do provide an essential service. The new syntax is an improvement over the C-style casts because it allows the compiler to check for errors that it couldn't with the old syntax. But the new syntax was made deliberately ugly, because casting is still an ugly and often unsafe operation.

Comment: "C++ tries to guard against Murphy, not Machiavelli" - (attributed alternatively to Bjarne Stroustrup, Herb Sutter, perhaps others).  @user803563: there are many other ways to do evil things to private data.  `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t)[0] = 'z'`

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not fine, but that's the whole point of `const_cast`. Generally, when a programmer overrides `const` a whole bunch of bad things may happen, and it is not advised to do that. I'm not sure if you can prevent someone from doing that though, because the point of `const_cast` is to override the protection generally provided by `const`.

Comment: I would also add that `const` is only there to "help to develop better and safer code" at compile time. The generated code is identical and nothing prevents these `const variables` to be constants.